# Cucumber JVM with Jenkin build some test cases stops in between

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am facing very weird issue. I am running cucumber jvm for java project on Jenkin with fork count 10.
I have more than 100 features files. Sometimes some features files **(not specific)** stop their execution without giving any error or exception. So because of that their json files is not getting created and records also get missed in the cucumber html report. Like it is not consistent it occurs 1 out of 8 times. But it is not giving any exceptions, warning or error so hard to track. Any one know what is issue and can help me with this issue.?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please split your execution, sometimes JVM getting peak. if our TCs running for long time, this will break our jenkins. so run your test by 20 to 30 features at a time.

**like**

> max 30 features / one jenkins build

for Eg: if you have 100 features with 500 scebarios

1. Build 1 - mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @first0to20"
2. Build 2 - mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @first21to40"
3. Build 3 - mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @first41to60"
4. Build 4 - mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @first61to80"
5. Build 5 - mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @first81to100"

Comment: Thank you for response. I will try this and will update here